# layout for qml custom tooltip

Tags: tooltip, qml

I'm trying to create a custom tooltip in qml but am not able to force the widget to be displayed on top of other items in the layout. I know why qml behaves that way, but I can't find a method to make it behave like I want to.

Here's the code that demonstrates the problem:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480


    Flow {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        spacing: 5

        Repeater {
            model: ["foo", "bar", "buzz"]

            delegate: Item {
                width: item.width
                height: item.height

                Rectangle {
                    id: item
                    color: "blue"
                    width: 100
                    height: 100

                    Text {
                        text: modelData
                        color: "white"
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }

                Rectangle {
                    width: 80
                    height: 120
                    color: "black"
                    anchors.left: item.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 5

                    Text {
                        text: "tooltip"
                        color: "white"
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to have is the tooltips on top of other items in the list, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

does it do the trick ?

```
ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Flow {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        spacing: 5

        Repeater {
            id: repeater;
            model: ["foo", "bar", "buzz"]

            delegate: Item {
                width: item.width
                height: item.height
                z: repeater.model.length - index

                Rectangle {
                    id: item
                    color: "blue"
                    width: 100
                    height: 100

                    Text {
                        text: modelData
                        color: "white"
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }

                Rectangle {
                    width: 80
                    height: 120
                    color: "black"
                    anchors.left: item.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 5

                    Text {
                        text: "tooltip"
                        color: "white"
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: z property does work only for siblings, but due to the structure of the item and the tool tip, this handy hack actually works except if you position the tool tip differently (e.g. on the other side). Then the solution fails :/

Comment: Turns out it's possible to assign a parent to a component explicitly, which makes the problem go away. Thanks BlueMagma for the inspiration ;)

Answer (score 2):

I advice you to do that in the way I do it in one of my application. Unfortunately I cannot get the source now so I will try to remember.

You can create custom tooltip element, for example:

**ToolTip.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle {
    color:"black"
    width:100
    height: 30
    property string label: "tooltip"
    Text {
        color: "white"
        text: parent.label
        anchors.fill: parent
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    }
}
```

Now, when some appropriate event occurs(onPositionChanged or onEntered) you can show your tooltip:

```js
onEntered: {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("ToolTip.qml");
    if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
        var tooltip = component.createObject(rootElement);
        tooltip.x = xxx ///
        tooltip.y = xxx /// here you should adjust position of tooltip
    }
}
```

*Pay attention - the parent of tooltip should be root element so you be sure that the tooltip item will be on top of the visual stack and not overlapped.*